# How to receive json data from cross domain server using AJAX?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

The API that I am calling in the ajax call returns json and does not support jsonp and I cannot change the API. When I use the below code snippet I get - 'missing ; before statement' error.

```
$.ajax({
         url: some_api,
         type: 'GET',
         dataType:"jsonp", 
         success: function(result){
                  alert("in success");
         },
         error : function(result){
                  alert(result);
                  alert("in error");
         }
});
```

When the above code snippet is executed the error block gets executed, though I am getting the correct JSON in response.How I can I possibly parse the JSON.

When I make the ajax call without dataType as jsonp, I get a Cross Origin request blocked error. Is there any workaround for the problem?

Comment: You can't. If the server does not support CORS or jsonp your only way it to proxy it from your server.

Comment: Try going through CORS once ?

Answer (score 0):

Make a slight modification -

```
$.ajax({
     url: some_api,
     type: 'GET',
     jsonp: "callback",
     dataType:"jsonp", 
     success: function(result){
              alert("in success");
     },
     error : function(result){
              alert(result);
              alert("in error");
     }
});
```